# Silverlight - Getting the Domain Information

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

How does a Silverlight application ask the browser what domain its being served up from?

**UPDATE:**
Make sure if your class doesn't already have this *using* statement add it at the top your class. This will help you on some of the examples you'll see online. It confused me for a bit.

```
  using System.Windows.Browser;
```

Comment: "Make sure if your class doesn't already have this using statement add it at the top your class": I usually paste in the code and let VS handle adding the using statements. You'll get warnings, then you can use the pulldown menu. If ya got it, use it.

Comment: What did you mean by pulldown menu for "usings"? is this a Resharper or CodeRush thing? or just something I never noticed in VS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about [HtmlDocument.DocumentUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmldocument.documenturi(VS.95).aspx)? That'd get you what you need. Page about browser interop **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd148642.aspx)**.

Answer (score 6):

As jcollum says you access the HtmlDocument.DocumentUri property to get lots of information on the host.  To answer the question in your comment this is how you do this in Page.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Browser;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class Page : UserControl
    {
        public Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string hostName = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Host;
            int port = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Port;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: + 1.Thanks.Any thoughts on this older question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345758/ I don't seem to be able to do much via VS2008 with the Silverlight add-on or Blend 2.  Im basically writing XAML by hand. Blend 2 doesn't even know what a <Button> is. I'd like to give answer points to someone.

Comment: @Bruno Tyndall:  See my answer to your older question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345758/